# Writing a mask for formatting the time

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

Currently if something like `"1230AM"` comes in, it will get formatted correctly and will show as

```
"12:30 AM"
```

But if something like **" 830AM"** comes in, it will get formatted and shown as **" 8:30 AM"** BUT I need it to show as `"08:30 AM"`
How can I do this? *Notice those blank spaces before the number 8*

The in-house built! masked text box is currently using a style defined like this which I think needs to be changed:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTimeMaskStyle" TargetType="controls:MyMaskedTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyMaskedTextBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="MaskType" Value="Standard" />
    <Setter Property="Mask" Value="##:## ll"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Placeholder" Value=" " />
</Style>
```

Comment: Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx), I think you just need to change to `00:00 ll`... Not 100% sure though.

Comment: nop, changed it to "83:0"

Comment: Try changing the changing "#" to "9" in mask.

Comment: @JBrooks nop, changed it to 83:0

Comment: Sounds like you will need a converter that trims the leading blank. Or fix the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't o that on the string format and mask level. Don't spend more time of that rabbit hole.

Couple of options I would suggest:

1. Find out where data is getting loaded and massage it before it
   gets to the binding.
2. Write a converter and do the same, massage it and make sure it
   has a leading zero if the th fitst character of data coming in is a
   space.